# UIScrollView and UITextView autosizing possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I have a view that is pushed onto the Screen via navigation controllers:

Inside is a UIScrollView.

Then inside the UIScrollView are a few static objects like Images and Labels.

Then comes the hard bit, There is a UITextView with its text loaded from different text files of varying length.

I need to be able to have the UITextView size dynamically to its contents, and the same for the UIScrollView. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float length = [yourText length];
textview.frame = CGRectMake(44, 87, 923, ceilf(length/142)*25);
```

Here `25` is the constant value assumed as text font width. From this you can set scrollview frame reference to the textview frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of following code. I had done that code for Label and same way you can do that with the help of text-field.

```
NSString *cellText = "Text Of Your Text-Field";
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your Font Name" size:FONT_SIZE];//UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(@"Width Of Your Text-Field", MAXFLOAT);//CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(220.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

int height = labelSize.height;

frame.origin.x = Starting Position of X;
frame.origin.y = Starting Position of Y;
frame.size.width = Width Of Your TextField;
frame.size.height = height;

UILabel *lblName = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
lblName.numberOfLines = 0;
lblName.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
lblName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
```

And same way you can do For the Scrollview. Just you have to set the Frame of that scrollview and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do something like this:

```
if ([textView length] > int//any number you want) {
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(//just adjust the size  an position here);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(//adjust scrollView size)
}
else if ([textView length] > int//just another number) {
    // you can continue looping that for how often you want
}
```

For the `int` in the if statement you check how long the text is. Based on that you adjust the size of both the scrollView and textView.